# List of figures produces error and doc does not compile

Tags: table-of-contents

I have this document in which I need a list of figures. It used to work already but for some reason the document won't compile anymore. Sorry, not a tex-Expert but the error messages below say I may have not closed a bracket or something. It all compiles nicely when I comment out `\listoffigures`

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}

\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{2cm}{1cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{4.3ex plus .2ex}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=23mm,
 right=23mm,
 top=23mm,
 bottom=23mm
 }

\title{Something}
\author{Team}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}


\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\euro{}}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, small]{caption}
\linespread{1.25}


\begin{document}

\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{Roman} %--- START

\section*{Acknowledgements}
\pagebreak

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak


\listoftables
\pagebreak

\listoffigures
\pagebreak

\pagenumbering{Roman} %--- END

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\section{Introduction}\label{sec:Introduction}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Photo.PNG}
    \caption[Shortcaption]{Longcaption.}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier



\end{document}
```

**I get this error:**

```
Argument of \NAT@@citetp has an extra }.

<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.1 ...xxxreturns \citep [}}{4}{figure.caption.1}
                                                  %
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \NAT@@citetp was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.1 ...xxxreturns \citep [}}{4}{figure.caption.1}
                                                  %
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

**And this error:**

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

<recently read> }
                 
l.1 ...xxxreturns \citep [}}{4}{figure.caption.1}
                                                  %
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...ces xxxxx \citep [}}
                                                  \hyper@linkend 
l.1 ...xxreturns \citep [}}{4}{figure.caption.1}
                                                  %
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the error if the caption is

```
\caption[Shortcaption \citep[p. 23]{xyz}]{Longcaption}
```

The problem is due to the bracket `]` that ends the wrong optional argument.

Fix:

```
\caption[Shortcaption {\citep[p. 23]{xyz}}]{Longcaption}
```

as the braces will hide the inner brackets.

By the way, you should use `\clearpage` rather than `\pagebreak` and remove the second `\pagenumbering{Roman}` that does nothing useful. Remove also `\setcounter{page}{1}`, because `\pagenumbering{arabic}` already takes care of it.